# Dual paraboloid point light shadows in deferred lighting setup

Tags: shadow-mapping, deferred-rendering

I've been playing around with [this tutorial/sample code](http://jcoluna.wordpress.com/2011/04/27/xna-4-0-light-pre-pass-casting-shadows/) that demonstrates a simple implementation of light-pre-pass, which is a type of deferred lighting setup.

I'm in the process of implementing point light shadows, using dual-paraboloid shadow maps. I'm following this description of DPM:
http://gamedevelop.eu/en/tutorials/dual-paraboloid-shadow-mapping.htm

I am able to create the shadow maps, and they seem to look fine.

I believe that the current problem I'm having is in my pixel shader that looks up a depth value in the shadow map when rendering point lights.

Here is my point light shader code:
http://olhovsky.com/shadow_mapping/PointLight.fx

The pixel shader function of interest is `PointLightMeshShadowPS`.

Does anyone see a glaring error in that function?

Hopefully someone has tackled this problem before :)

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the images above, the post's shadows do not match up with the positions of the posts, so some transformation is wrong somewhere...

This is what it looks like when the point light is very close to the ground (almost touching the ground).

[image]

As the point light moves closer to the ground, the shadows come together and touch along the line where the two shadow maps meet (that is, along the plane where the light camera was flipped to capture the two shadow maps).

---

Edit:

Further information:

[image]

When I move the point light away from the origin, there is a line parallel to the light camera's "right" vector that clips the shadow. The above image shows the result of moving the point light to the left. If I move the point light to the right, there is an equivalent clipping line on the right instead. So I think this indicates that I'm transforming something incorrectly in the pixel shader, like I thought.

---

Edit:
To make this question more clear, here are a few pieces of code.

Here is the code that I currently use to draw a shadowed **spot light**. This works, and uses shadow mapping as you'd expect.

```
VertexShaderOutputMeshBased SpotLightMeshVS(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    VertexShaderOutputMeshBased output = (VertexShaderOutputMeshBased)0;    
    output.Position = mul(input.Position, WorldViewProjection);

    //we will compute our texture coords based on pixel position further
    output.TexCoordScreenSpace = output.Position;
    return output;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Pixel shader to compute spot lights with shadows
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
float4 SpotLightMeshShadowPS(VertexShaderOutputMeshBased input) : COLOR0
{
    //as we are using a sphere mesh, we need to recompute each pixel position into texture space coords
    float2 screenPos = PostProjectionSpaceToScreenSpace(input.TexCoordScreenSpace) + GBufferPixelSize;
    //read the depth value
    float depthValue = tex2D(depthSampler, screenPos).r;

    //if depth value == 1, we can assume its a background value, so skip it
    //we need this only if we are using back-face culling on our light volumes. Otherwise, our z-buffer
    //will reject this pixel anyway

    //if depth value == 1, we can assume its a background value, so skip it
    clip(-depthValue + 0.9999f);

    // Reconstruct position from the depth value, the FOV, aspect and pixel position
    depthValue*=FarClip;

    //convert screenPos to [-1..1] range
    float3 pos = float3(TanAspect*(screenPos*2 - 1)*depthValue, -depthValue);

    //light direction from current pixel to current light
    float3 lDir = LightPosition - pos;

    //compute attenuation, 1 - saturate(d2/r2)
    float atten = ComputeAttenuation(lDir);

    // Convert normal back with the decoding function
    float4 normalMap = tex2D(normalSampler, screenPos);
    float3 normal = DecodeNormal(normalMap);

    lDir = normalize(lDir);

    // N dot L lighting term, attenuated
    float nl = saturate(dot(normal, lDir))*atten;

    //spot light cone
    half spotAtten = min(1,max(0,dot(lDir,LightDir) - SpotAngle)*SpotExponent);
    nl *= spotAtten;

    //reject pixels outside our radius or that are not facing the light
    clip(nl -0.00001f);

    //compute shadow attenuation

    float4 lightPosition = mul(mul(float4(pos,1),CameraTransform), MatLightViewProjSpot);

    // Find the position in the shadow map for this pixel
    float2 shadowTexCoord = 0.5 * lightPosition.xy / 
                            lightPosition.w + float2( 0.5, 0.5 );
    shadowTexCoord.y = 1.0f - shadowTexCoord.y;
    //offset by the texel size
    shadowTexCoord += ShadowMapPixelSize;

    // Calculate the current pixel depth
    // The bias is used to prevent floating point errors 
    float ourdepth = (lightPosition.z / lightPosition.w) - DepthBias;

    nl = ComputeShadowPCF7Linear(nl, shadowTexCoord, ourdepth);

    float4 finalColor;

    //As our position is relative to camera position, we dont need to use (ViewPosition - pos) here
    float3 camDir = normalize(pos);

    // Calculate specular term
    float3 h = normalize(reflect(lDir, normal));
    float spec = nl*pow(saturate(dot(camDir, h)), normalMap.b*50);
    finalColor = float4(LightColor * nl, spec); 

    //output light
    return finalColor * LightBufferScale;
}
```

Now here is the **point light** code that I'm using, which has some sort of bug in the transformation into light space when using the shadow maps:

```
VertexShaderOutputMeshBased PointLightMeshVS(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    VertexShaderOutputMeshBased output = (VertexShaderOutputMeshBased)0;    
    output.Position = mul(input.Position, WorldViewProjection);

    //we will compute our texture coords based on pixel position further
    output.TexCoordScreenSpace = output.Position;
    return output;
}

float4 PointLightMeshShadowPS(VertexShaderOutputMeshBased input) : COLOR0
{
    // as we are using a sphere mesh, we need to recompute each pixel position 
    // into texture space coords
    float2 screenPos = 
        PostProjectionSpaceToScreenSpace(input.TexCoordScreenSpace) + GBufferPixelSize;

    // read the depth value
    float depthValue = tex2D(depthSampler, screenPos).r;

    // if depth value == 1, we can assume its a background value, so skip it
    // we need this only if we are using back-face culling on our light volumes. 
    // Otherwise, our z-buffer will reject this pixel anyway
    clip(-depthValue + 0.9999f);

    // Reconstruct position from the depth value, the FOV, aspect and pixel position
    depthValue *= FarClip;

    // convert screenPos to [-1..1] range
    float3 pos = float3(TanAspect*(screenPos*2 - 1)*depthValue, -depthValue);

    // light direction from current pixel to current light
    float3 lDir = LightPosition - pos;

    // compute attenuation, 1 - saturate(d2/r2)
    float atten = ComputeAttenuation(lDir);

    // Convert normal back with the decoding function
    float4 normalMap = tex2D(normalSampler, screenPos);
    float3 normal = DecodeNormal(normalMap);

    lDir = normalize(lDir);

    // N dot L lighting term, attenuated
    float nl = saturate(dot(normal, lDir))*atten;

    /* shadow stuff */

    float4 lightPosition = mul(mul(float4(pos,1),CameraTransform), LightViewProj);

    //float4 lightPosition = mul(float4(pos,1), LightViewProj);
    float posLength = length(lightPosition);
    lightPosition /= posLength;

    float ourdepth = (posLength - NearClip) / (FarClip - NearClip) - DepthBias;
    //float ourdepth = (lightPosition.z / lightPosition.w) - DepthBias;

    if(lightPosition.z > 0.0f)
    {
        float2 vTexFront;
        vTexFront.x =  (lightPosition.x /  (1.0f + lightPosition.z)) * 0.5f + 0.5f; 
        vTexFront.y =  1.0f - ((lightPosition.y /  (1.0f + lightPosition.z)) * 0.5f + 0.5f);    

        nl = ComputeShadow(FrontShadowMapSampler, nl, vTexFront, ourdepth);
    }
    else
    {
        // for the back the z has to be inverted        
        float2 vTexBack;
        vTexBack.x =  (lightPosition.x /  (1.0f - lightPosition.z)) * 0.5f + 0.5f; 
        vTexBack.y =  1.0f - ((lightPosition.y /  (1.0f - lightPosition.z)) * 0.5f + 0.5f); 

        nl = ComputeShadow(BackShadowMapSampler, nl, vTexBack, ourdepth);
    }

    /* shadow stuff */

    // reject pixels outside our radius or that are not facing the light
    clip(nl - 0.00001f);

    float4 finalColor;
    //As our position is relative to camera position, we dont need to use (ViewPosition - pos) here
    float3 camDir = normalize(pos);

    // Calculate specular term
    float3 h = normalize(reflect(lDir, normal));
    float spec = nl*pow(saturate(dot(camDir, h)), normalMap.b*100);
    finalColor = float4(LightColor * nl, spec);

    return finalColor * LightBufferScale;
}
```

Comment: and you say shadow maps themselves are having no problem/ (I mean if you burn the shadow maps to to texturemap they'll darken correct spots?)

Comment: Are you 100% sure the FOV of the camera rendering from the light source's position is correct?

Comment: The camera rendering from the light's source position does not have a projection matrix, because the projection is done manually in order to have the paraboloid warp. I'll check that code though, good idea Roy T.

Comment: Gajet: "I mean if you burn the shadow maps to to texturemap they'll darken correct spots?" The shadow maps store shadows in light space, if I look at the map, there's no easy way to know for certain that they are correct because I see them in screenspace. What is a "texturemap" -- you mean a texture? Shadow maps *are* textures.

Comment: Roy T.: Moving the light around reveals that the shadow map gets clipped, so there is a problem with the transformation when actually using the shadow, not just when creating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With PIX you can debug pixels isolated, maybe you find the error in this way.
FOV or a projection error is a hot hint.
Or have you forgot the world transformation?!

Comment: you can also try debuging with NVidia-fxComposer

Comment: I don't think that staring at the assembly code values is going to help me very much at this point, because I'm having trouble understanding how the transformation should be done in the first place. So seeing what value is in register 10, or wherever, is not really going to help.

Comment: "Or have you forgot the world transformation?!" I actually did forget to apply the world transform when creating the shadow maps -- doh! This works now, leaving all the shaders as I had them.

Answer (score 2):

Hey Olhovsky, nice challenging question. I know your pain, I implemented Deferred Shading, Inferred Lighting and shadows in my last job. It was really great fun, but lots of pain too when it didn't work as expected.

I think the advice with PIX is actually a good one. You don't have to mess with the assembler instructions of the shader, but you can look at the shadow maps and other render targets, select a pixel and call its pixel shader and step through it and also its vertex-shader.

General debug tricks for this kind of situations include simplification of the scene.

One that comes to my mind is: put the camera at the same position as the light source with the same fovy and other attributes as in the lighting pass. Now you can easily compare the values in the pixel-shader. The pixel-xy in the normal render-pass for your current object should be the same as the calculated pixel-xy for the lookup in the shadowmap, as long as it has the same resolution.

Another one is switch to orthographic projection, render something easy, predictable and checkable. The simpler the better you can check each calculation step.

Other than that, can you show how you create the matrix that calculates the position in the shadow-map for the current pixel, that is the transformation from screen-space to light-space?

Comment: Just seeing the shadow map is a Parabloid, that makes it even harder to debug and the idea to put the camera at the lights position to compare current pixel position and position in the shadow-map won't work, nevermind :)

Comment: If you're interested, send me an email at kris@olhovsky.com, and I'll reply with a copy of my project. Otherwise:
The `CameraTransform` matrix is actually the world matrix of the camera currently viewing the scene.
The `LightViewProj` matrix is actually just the world matrix of the light, as the view matrix of the light is just the identity matrix.

Comment: Can you make a simple C++ project with it? There should also be the parabloid transformation involved right?

Comment: The paraboloid transformation is in the pixel shader I linked in the question. My C++ skills are too limited to drum up a quick C++ project that encapsulates the entire deferred rendering pipeline I think :) However, if you're proficient with C++, then I think it shouldn't be too hard to read my C# code. Especially since most of the concern is really in the pixel shader, and perhaps with the matricies passed to it.

Comment: I was refering to g_mDPView and g_mDPWorldView. Can you show how they are calculated.

Comment: Ok, I don't have XNA and C# running here.

Comment: I would start removing the parabloid projection from those matrices and see if it works with a simple plane as shadow map. If it works, there is something wrong with the parabloid projection.

Comment: There are no g_mDPView or g_mDPWorldView in my shader. That is the DPM paper's shader that you're looking at. I can't use that shader directly, since he assumes forward rendering, which I'm not using. This is the source of the trouble. I have a working spot light with shadows here:
http://olhovsky.com/shadow_mapping/Lights.fx
(Look at `SpotLightMeshShadowPS`.)

And my point light shadows are here:
http://olhovsky.com/shadow_mapping/PointLight.fx
(Look at `PointLightMeshShadowPS`.)

Comment: `g_mDPView` in the DPM paper's sample, is the same as my `LightViewProj`, and it is just the identity 4x4 matrix, with the bottom left 3 entries replaced with the light's position.

Comment: I have simplified my shader to make it easier to see what's going on:
http://olhovsky.com/shadow_mapping/PointLight.fx

If you compare my vertex and pixel shader to the DPM paper's shaders here
http://gamedevelop.eu/en/tutorials/downloads/dual-paraboloid-shadow-mapping.fx
Then it might make my mistake more clear. I'm pretty sure I'm not transforming into light space correctly, as a result of needing to apply the deferred principles to the forward rendered example, if you understand my meaning.

Comment: Ok, in which matrix did you put the parabloid projection? Can't find something with a quick look.

Comment: There is no such matrix. The paraboloid projection is done in the pixel shader manually.

Comment: That projection is done after the line `/* shadow stuff */`.

Comment: Ok, so it should be easy to remove the parabloid-part and test if it works with a normal plane, right? Sorry its too late for me here to jump into the code and theres too much of it :)

Comment: But again, generally I would try to test each calculation step separately, removing the parabloid projection is such a steps.

Comment: Computing the paraboloid projection is part of computing the shadow map coordinates. Removing it would not tell me very much, because it is part of what I'm trying to debug in this question.

Comment: So you are sure the problem is that parabloid projection? I didn't mean to remove the entire calculation of the shadow map coordinates, only the parabloid part, projecting onto a normal plane. However, if you are already sure its the parabloid it shouldn't be too hard to fix

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that replacing the paraboloid projection with a planar projection is a big change. When you say "the paraboloid projection", we're not talking about a matrix multiplication.

Comment: The way to find the position in the shadow map is given by the simple pixel shader in the DPM sample:
http://gamedevelop.eu/en/tutorials/downloads/dual-paraboloid-shadow-mapping.fx
The way I look up a shadow map depth value in my **spot** light is in my simple pixel shader here (note I said spot light, the spot lights work, and they use planar shadows):
http://olhovsky.com/shadow_mapping/Lights.fx

So all that remains really is to fix the way I'm wrongly converting from a forward to deferred setup.

Comment: You mentioned earlier that there's a lot of code to read, but really, there's only maybe 10-15 lines of interest in my point light shader. I will try to separate out the important code in the question, give me a few minutes to do that.

Comment: Shouldn't it only be used in 2 places? Once writing the shadow-buffer and once reading it in 2 pixel-shaders? Putting it in a separate function would solve the problem and it could easily be changed. But I might underestimate the problem, didn't really check it.

Comment: Regarding the lot of code, its a lot of code given the time here, its midnight ;)

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. The paraboloid projection is fine. When you say "paraboloid projection", I don't really know what you're talking about specifically though, because finding the position in the shadow map is part of doing the "paraboloid projection". The paraboloid projection consists of computing the depth value (in my shader `ourdepth`) and finding the shadow coordinates. If I replace these two things with the same type of projection used in the spot lights, then what would that tell me?

Comment: If you look at the ~10 lines of shadow code, you'll see what I mean hopefully :)

Comment: It will tell you whether the bug is in that part of the code or not. But I didn't know you were already sure that the problem is there. However, if you are sure I would take that piece of code and investigate it in a simPle test app, completely without shaders and other stuff, only checking if the projection works as expected, plus it has the nice side effect to understand that part better.

Comment: I will check that part here tomorrow

Comment: I was trying to point out that the paraboloid projection is built into the other parts of the code, you can't isolate it and test "paraboloid projection" by itself easily. If I remove the paraboloid projection, that won't tell me anything useful. Even if I used a planar projection for the point light shadow, how do I know which shadow map to sample from (there's two, one per hemisphere), and how would I know what a "correct" result looks like? You'd be wrapping a single plane (that is meant to represent a hemisphere) around a sphere.

Comment: In short, the paraboloid projection is a copy-paste of the DPM paper's code. It works. The problem is figuring out how to set it up to work with deferred rendering. I have displayed how a spot light with shadows is done in the deferred set up, in the question. And we can see how a point light is done using forward rendering. This should be enough to figure out how to implement the point light with deferred rendering.

Comment: I think I discovered what the problem is. I was treating `pos` as the world space position of the pixel, after this line `float3 pos = float3(TanAspect*(screenPos*2 - 1)*depthValue, -depthValue);` in the function *PointLightMeshShadowPS*, but actually this is the position of the pixel in the camera's view space. I'm not sure how to fix this yet.

Comment: Then a transformation with the inverse of the camera-matrix should do it and you should have it in world-space, right?

Comment: Perhaps yes, but this computation will then be done millions of times per frame. If I don't have to do that multiplication, that would be better. I guess I'll try that for now, and see if I can just get it working first :)

Comment: Hmm, although I guess I can create a matrix that is the inverse of the view matrix multiplied by the light matrix.. then I only have to do one multiplication by that matrix, which is equivalent to the other way anyway! I hope this works :) Thanks Maik, +1 for talking this through with me.

Comment: Anytime @Olhovsky :)